# How to keep a rendered pdf file inside syncfusion pdfViewer on page refresh or navigation

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf-generation, ejs, syncfusion

I am using a syncfusion pdfViewer control with angular. I would like the renderered document to stay in the control even when I leave or refresh the page. When  I navigate tabs or when I go
to another page and come back to the pdf page I would still like to view it the way it was initially loaded. Currently the control reloads and rerenders the pdf when I go navigate
back to the page that has the pdf.

So far I have tried enablePersistence = true , rendering 3 initial pages with N render

HTML

PDFViewer

```
   <div id="Preview">
        <ejs-pdfviewer id="pdfViewer" [serviceUrl]='hostedUrl' [documentPath]='localBase64Url' [initialRenderPages]='initialRender'  style="height:800px;display:block"></ejs-pdfviewer>
    </div>
```

Tabs

```
  <li [ngbNavItem]="2"   [disabled]="!docsTabDisabled" (click)="OnStorePDFState()">
        <a ngbNavLink>
            <i class="la la-info-circle" ></i> Source Document
        </a>
        <ng-template ngbNavContent>
            <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="SourceDocumentTab"></ng-template>
        </ng-template>
    </li>
```

Typescript

```
localBase64Url = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + data.file;
public hostedUrl = 'https://ej2services.syncfusion.com/production/web-services/api/pdfviewer'

 constructor(){
     this.route.params.subscribe((p) => {this.getFile();}
}

public getFile(this.fileId){
  this.testService.getUrl(`get-file/${this.fileId}`)
     .subscribe((data) => {
       this.test = data.test;
        
       if (data.file) {
         const base64Url = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + data.file;
         this.localBase64Url = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + data.file;
         //window.localStorage()
         this.storageService.saveCurrentTestPreview(base64Url); 
         console.log(base64Url); 
         this.pdfViewer.isDestroyed = false; 
         //this.pdfViewer.ngOnDestroy
         this.pdfViewer.dataBind(); 
             if(!this.localBase64Url){
              console.log("not loading from local")
             this.pdfViewer.load(base64Url, '');
             }
        this.pdfViewer.enablePersistence = true;
        this.pdfViewer.getLocalData(); 
        viewer.detachUnloadEvent(); 
        }
    }
}

 public OnStorePDFState(){
  
    if(!this.docsTabDisabled)return; 
    this.pdfViewer.getPersistData(); 
    this.pdfViewer.getLocalData();
    const viewer = this.pdfViewer.documentLoad({
      enableToolbar: false,
      enableNavigationToolbar: false,
      documentPath:this.localBase64Url,
      serviceUrl: this.hostedUrl,
       }); 
      viewer.appendTo('#pdfviewer');
      viewer.enablePersistence = true, 
      viewer.getPersistData(); 
      viewer.getLocalData(); 
      viewer.detachUnloadEvent(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the provided sample, upon loading the document, the 'documentLoad' event is triggered. By utilizing this event, we obtain the base64 of the document using the 'savsAsBlob' method and store it in local storage. After a refresh or navigation, upon returning to the PDF Viewer, we retrieve the base64 string from local storage and load it in the PDFViewer within the 'created' event.

Code snippet:

```
 documentLoad(args){
   var data;
   var base64data;
   var viewer = (<any>document.getElementById('pdfViewer'))
     .ej2_instances[0];
   setTimeout(()=>{
     // Get the base64 of the loaded document
     viewer.saveAsBlob().then(function (value) {
         data = value;
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.readAsDataURL(data);
         reader.onload = () => { 
             base64data = reader.result; 
             console.log(base64data);
             localStorage.setItem("CurrentDoc", base64data); 
         };
     })
   }, 1000)
 }

 created(){
   console.log("called");
   var viewer = (<any>document.getElementById('pdfViewer'))
   .ej2_instances[0];
   var currentDoc = localStorage.getItem("CurrentDoc");
   if(currentDoc){
     // loaded document from local storage
     viewer.load(currentDoc);  
   } 
 }
```

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uaj8wr-sdzurg?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp.component.html,package.json,src%2Fapp.component.css

This example reloads the most recently opened document in the PDF Viewer when refreshing the page or returning from another page. Nevertheless, it is not feasible to preserve the previous viewing state or the specific page that was being viewed; only the last loaded document can be retained.